# Which platforms will support Visual Studio 11?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

We all know that windows 8 will be released very soon, and that Visual Studio 11 will be released too. With Visual Studio 11 you can make Metro UI apps exactly like WP7.

My question is that if we program with VS 11, is it supported on Windows 7, Vista and XP?

Comment: Windows 7, Milestone 1 was released Jan. 2008, and the final release was built July 2009. I'd bet it'll be over a year before Windows 8 is released (and may easily be closer to two years).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't know what the scheduled release is, but I know that they're ahead of schedule.

Comment: @SnOrfus: IIRC, they've repeatedly said they're not going to be driven by a schedule, but release it when it's ready. Things like beta testing, however, take substantial time no matter what. They involve too many people (and such) to happen really quickly. There's also considerably negotiation with manufacturers over what will be required of certified hardware and such.

Comment: The question is: can you target 7, Vista, XP with MSVC2011?  I guess similarly, are there new 2011 CRTs to install on older platforms?

Comment: @Steve-o - Of course you can target those platforms unless your using WinRT within the application. .NET Framework 4.5 is still seperate from WinRT. You currently cannot target a certain version of Windows, if it currently Windows 7, then it will continue to work on Windows 8, thats the official word from Microsoft.  You need Windows 8 to create a Metro UI application, since you would be unable to test it on anything except Windows 8, would be counter productive to allow that

Comment: For what it is worth, it's termed Visual Studio 11, as in version 11. It may or may not be released in 2011. Likely not at this point.

Comment: In Visual Studio 11 new metro-style applications can be runned in the emulator (like Windows Phone 7 emulator), so I think that it will be possible to release it for Windows 7.

Answer (score 7):

You can install VS11, but you will not be able to develop Metro UI unless you're in Windows 8.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/toolsforwinapps/thread/0155ffb8-b526-46f3-9286-3befd5563b32

That is why they are giving you the Win8 Dev Preview image that you can install VS11 Ultimate and test it out.

[Windows 8 Developer Preview Downloads Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516)
[VS11 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/hh127353)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to install VS11 and develop Metro apps:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 11 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543) will only run on Windows 7 or Server 2008 and above.

Targeting depends on the project type. Windows 8 Metro app projects can only be built when running VS11 on the Windows 8 Consumer Preview. But the MFC/CRT etc. can target down to Vista.

What sort of application were you thinking of building?